# simple put request for nodejs without express

Tags: node.js

I need to be able to upload a zip file to a brightsign unit and thinking of creating a rest api which I can make a put request to send the zip file.

But the problem is that all examples I find is using frameworks such as express. **Is it possible to make a rest API handling a PUT requst in nodejs without using extra frameworks?**

The problem is that I can only use modules that does not need a "configuration" step on the brightsign player. So I can use modules that only contain plain javascript (I hope my explanation makes sense).

Comment: what is the problem with using express, do you mind extending that?

Comment: I need to be able to run it on a Brightsign player. It only supports modules that does not require "configuration" step when the module is installed. As I understand it, some modules needs to run a step when installed that configures the module for the target machine. BrightSign players can't use those kind of modules.

Comment: can you go into more detail about the type of module that dopes that? I have not heard of modules that do this. I have created an express server on my device and I simply run npm install on my local machine and copy the node _modules directory over to the storage device on the bs player. Alternatively you can bundle the express app with webpack or babel.

Answer (score 4):

## Vanilla ([NodeJS HTTP API](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html))

You will need to listen for the PUT somehow :

```
const http = require('http');
const querystring = require('querystring');
const server = http.createServer().listen(3000);

server.on('request', function (req, res) {
    if (req.method == 'PUT') { //PUT Only
        var body = '';
        req.on('data', function (data){body += data;});
        req.on('end', function () {
            var PUT = querystring.parse(body);
            console.log(PUT);
            res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'})
            res.write('\n[request received successfully]\n'); res.end();
        });
    }else{res.end();}
});
```

You can test it out using `curl` :

```
curl -X PUT -d destPath=/home/usr/images -d fileName=selfie.png -d fileData=base64string localhost:3000
```

---

In **express** is much simpler, comment if you need an express example

Comment: Thank you for your example. Maybe I'm dumb, but when printing the body I only get the request string. I was thinking that the data of the file would be in the request somehow. Is the curl command sending the file?

Comment: Yes but this is a simple example, you would have to replace `-d fileData=base64string` , change **base64string** for an actual base64 string and then add some logic in the server to manipulate the base64 that is passed in the query string, for example : check for mime type, size, and if everything seems ok, then store as a file using the `destPath` and `fileName` to specify where and with what name to store the file. (I suggest checking if everything is ok with those parameters too, to avoid unexpected crashes due to badly formatted client requests [missing the parameters you are using])