# Search mysql database with node in html

Tags: html, mysql, node.js, ajax, select

I connected a database to node and am trying to create an HTML page to search the database. I would rather not use EJS. I think I have to use a POST request in the HTML AJAX and connect it with a POST request in node.

Here is what I'm thinking:

```
app.post("/cities/:city", function(req, res) {
    db.hospitalinfo.findAll({
        where: { city: req.params.city }
    }).then(function (result) {
        res.json(result);
        console.log("res--->"+result);
        console.log("req--->"+req.params.city);
    });
});
```

Here's the HTML:

```
<form id="author-form" method="POST">
      <select id ="dropDownId">
          <option value="Opp" >Opp</option>
          <option value="Boaz">Boaz</option>
      </select>
      <input class="SubmitButton" type="submit"  id="click" style="font-size:20px;" />
</form>
```

Now here's where I'm stuck. I need to grab the value from the select statement:

```
var nameInput = $("#dropDownId :selected");
```

I don't know how to actually send nameInput to the URL so my post statement will work. I probably don't completely understand how these routes work. This is my first project by myself. I would like to grab the nameInput, send it to the server via AJAX, and search my database with it. Right now it's returning an empty object. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Here's an example of an API route without ExpressJS: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45864677/simple-put-request-for-nodejs-without-express

Comment: I'm using express I just don't want to use a backend templating language like EJS if I can avoid it because I can't access the DOM with it. Maybe there is a way I don't know.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make a Ajax call to node server. For that you need to stop the default submit of form.

```
event.preventDefault();
```

can be used to stop the normal flow of submitting the form.

Here is an example of ajax call

```
(document).ready(function() {
    // process the form
    $('form').submit(function(event) {
        // get the form data
        // there are many ways to get this data using jQuery (you can use the class or id also)
        var formData = {
            'name'              : $('input[name=name]').val(),
            'email'             : $('input[name=email]').val(),
        };

        // process the form
        $.ajax({
              type: "GET", // define the type of HTTP verb we want to use (POST for our form)
              url: "http://localhost:5000/example" // the url where we want to POST
              data: formData,
              dataType: 'json', // what type of data do we expect back from the server 
              success: function (data) {
                    console.log(data.result);
                    // perform required changes
                  },
              error: function (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                  }          
               });

        // stop the form from submitting the normal way and refreshing the page
        event.preventDefault();
    });

});
```

you can refer this site for more details [making ajax calls](https://scotch.io/tutorials/submitting-ajax-forms-with-jquery)

I have modified the code taken from there.

Comment: you have to pass the nameInput with the url : "http://localhost:5000/example" + nameInput in ajax query and make changes in success function